# Multiple background image in css

Tags: css

Can we add multiple background-images one after another from top-bottom using CSS only(not bootstrap, jquery etc)?[Output.jpg is expected design of page with multiple images and scrolling property of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Eg0I.jpg)

Comment: CSS and HTML, yes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds

Comment: @Gems are you asking how to layer one background image on top of another or are you asking how to sequentially have one image at the top then another image beneath it as one scrolls down the page?

Comment: I don't want images in the layer but would like to add images one by one horizontally so that if images go beyond the size of the screen, it bring scrolling properties to the screen to cover all images.                                                Let me know if it's clear.

Comment: Correcting my word:  one by one vertically not horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for more image in background you need to set the background to the division:

CSS:

```
#image1 {
     background: url(image1.jpg)
     height: 100%;
}
#image2 {
     background: url(image2.jpg)
     height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:`

```
<div id="image1"></div>
<div id="image2"></div>
```

Probably this will work, but if you want a scrolling property you need jQuery or you add a button at the end of every division and set the href to the next division, example:

```
<div id="image1">
    <a class="next-page" href="#image2">next-page</a>
</div>
<div id="image2"></div>
```

Tell me if this works

Comment: @ Nicolò Lafasciano                                                                          
 Above code with CSS and HTML worked well. Margin property also helped here. Thanks. 
 
 #image1{
  background-image:url(admin.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }
 #image2{
  margin-top:65%;
  background-image:url(accountant.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width:200%
 }